# Convert epoch millis to "Jun 6, 2017 3:53:46 PM"

Tags: java, datetime, localdate, localdatetime

(Using Java 11) How can I convert the following epoch long value:

```
long epochLong = 1496760826841L
```

into this string:

```
Jun 6, 2017 3:53:46 PM
```

Comment: [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Please search before asking. Very similar questions have been answered more than once before.

Comment: Let Java localize for you. `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_496_760_826_841L).atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Porto-Novo")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.US))` gives `Jun 6, 2017, 3:53:46 PM` (tested on Java 17).

Answer (score 3):

This should work if you want `Jun 06, 2017  3:53:46 PM` irrespective of the JVM machine time zone change the `triggerTime` to this

> LocalDateTime triggerTime =
> LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis),
> ZoneId.of("+01:00"));

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long epochMillis = 1496760826841L;
        LocalDateTime triggerTime =
                LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis),
                        TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());
        DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter
                = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy  h:m:s a");
        
        System.out.println(triggerTime.format(parseFormatter));
    }
```

Comment: Only don’t use `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. To get the JVM’s default time zone, just use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. A good answer, thanks.